# looking for a node after finding a specific node

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to save the html of a node to localstorage. Here is what I am trying to do. First look for the "strong" node and if the html of this node is "AM" only then will I get the time from the span node with class of "time". It seems to work but not the way I would like it to. Rather it gets the time string from the very first span rather than the span that is above the "strong" node with html of "AM". I hope this is clear if not I will try to explain as best I can.

**HTML**

```
<div>
<span class="time">Today 07:11 PM</span>
<strong>PM</strong>
</div>

<div>
<span class="time">Today 07:21 PM</span>
<strong>AM</strong>
</div>
```

**Code**

```
checkTime = setInterval(function(){
    // get html of the 1st node
    var firstNode = $("strong").html();

    // if 1st node html is "AM" save time to local storage
    if (firstNode == "AM") {
      var userClock = $("span.time").html();
      localStorage.setItem('clock', userClock);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
checkTime = setInterval(function(){
    // get html of the 1st node
    var firstNode = $('strong:contains("AM")');

    // if 1st node html is "AM" save time to local storage
      var userClock = firstNode.prev('span.time').html();
      localStorage.setItem('clock', userClock);
}, 1000);
```

**[Live Proof](http://jsfiddle.net/k9UGa/)**